# Detect connection to bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-8.0-oreo

According to the current documentation, the intents ACL_CONNECTED and ACL_DISCONNECTED are not in the exception list. My app uses these intents to start a foreground service when a specific device is connected. The only other way would be to use ACTION_STATE_CHANGED but it seems it has a different goal. So now it seems impossible to start a service when a specific BT device is connected with android 8. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Keep your `targetSdkVersion` below 26, and try to stay off of the battery blame list.

Comment: Background optimizations can be applied even if your target SDK is lower than 26

Comment: Only if you are on the battery blame list and the user decides to apply them. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#overview): "By default, these restrictions only apply to apps that target O. However, users can enable these restrictions for any app from the Settings screen, even if the app has not targetted O." See also [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/05/24/android-o-background-limitations-not-just-targetsdkversion-o.html).

Comment: Yes, I know. It's the reason why I said "can be applied". I can't stop user to apply the restrictions. It seems a really weak policy to just keep target sdk below 26.

Comment: However, beyond that, your options are limited (everlasting foreground service, or polling via `JobScheduler` or `AlarmManager`).

Comment: I hate Google now :/

Comment: @CommonsWare Your post is interesting but from my test I found that if the app is ignoring battery optimizations, it can start a service with unlimited time.

Comment: If it is a foreground service, correct, and I don't think there is anything in my post that contradicts that. From that service, you can register for broadcasts dynamically and avoid the restriction. However, it means that you have a service running all the time, and historically users have not appreciated that. I tried to get [implicit broadcasts supported via a store-and-forward system](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37249255) but got shot down.

Comment: @CommonsWare No it was just an additional information to your post. You didn't say anything about this point but it's important. An app is ignoring optimizations has no constraint about the startService from a receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of August 14, 2018, `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` *are* on the Implicit Broadcast Exception list:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Also included are `ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED` for both Headsets and A2DP.

You should still be able detect connections.